# How to get bitcoin transaction nonce from transaction signature?

Tags: signature, nonce, secp256k1

Subj.

Looking for a code for calculate/get bitcoin transaction nonce. Help me please.

???

Thank you.

Comment: You cannot. If you could compute the nonce of a signature, you could also compute its private key.

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to assume by 'nonce', that you're referring to the value that, when hashed with the rest of the data in the block, equates to a value that's lower than the "target" (difficulty) for the epoch.

If that is the case, then you can get this information from a block explorer website like Blockcypher (url - https://live.blockcypher.com).

As an example, I chose to look at the block submitted and validated most recently (block height 706,890).

[image]

Clicking the hyperlinked block height # in the screenshot above will take you here - https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/block/000000000000000000067119c310ecee2c2f4b79b96e2a616ff93bf31236e1d6/

Once you arrive at that page, you have to click the 'Advanced Details' button, which will pull expand the information you get shown.

[image]

Once you do this, you just need to scroll down the page a bit and you'll be able to see that block's "winning nonce".

[image]

Boom, that's it.

If this isn't what you were looking for, just write a comment to this 'answer' clarifying and I'll see if I can clear anything up for you.

Comment: Nonce of a block is same nonce of bitcoin transaction ? Thank You.

Comment: I believe this answer is confused; OP is asking about the ECDSA nonce in signatures, not about the block mining nonce.

Comment: Hey @PieterWuille , I don't disagree with you (at first glance looking at the question), but given the asker's unfamiliarity with how Bitcoin works (from a distance), I was a bit skeptical that they were asking about something as involved as the deterministic nonce generated per signature on the protocol. A question like that would likely be more appropriate for the (pure) cryptography StackExchange